# Add multiple UITextFields on UIButton click

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uitextfield

I have pretty confusing problem. I have view that is defined as company details, that contains 5 `UITextFields`, and `UITextFields` are: address, city, zip code, etc. Now, there is `UIButton` for adding one more address, that adds same view but it needs to be filled with different data. I have no solution for this, this is pretty much what I've done:

```
 self.officeLocationsLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(LEFT_MARGIN, self.viewForCompanyProfileImage.frame.origin.y+self.viewForCompanyProfileImage.frame.size.height+SPACE_MARGIN*2, SCREEN_WIDTH-LEFT_MARGIN*2, 40)];
    self.officeLocationsLabel.text = AMLocalizedString(@"officeLocations_text", nil);
    [self.officeLocationsLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [self.officeLocationsLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20]];
    [self.mainScroll addSubview:self.officeLocationsLabel];

    self.streetAddressTextField = [self createTextFieldWithFrame:CGRectMake(LEFT_MARGIN, self.officeLocationsLabel.frame.origin.y+self.officeLocationsLabel.frame.size.height+SPACE_MARGIN, SCREEN_WIDTH-LEFT_MARGIN*2, 40) andPlaceholder:AMLocalizedString(@"streetAddress_text", nil)];
    [self.mainScroll addSubview:self.streetAddressTextField];
    self.streetAddressLine = [self createLineUsingOrigins:self.streetAddressTextField];
    [self.mainScroll addSubview:self.streetAddressLine];

    self.additionalAddresInfoTextField = [self createTextFieldWithFrame:CGRectMake(LEFT_MARGIN, self.streetAddressLine.frame.origin.y+self.streetAddressLine.frame.size.height+SPACE_MARGIN, SCREEN_WIDTH-LEFT_MARGIN*2, 40) andPlaceholder:AMLocalizedString(@"additionalAddress_text", nil)];
    [self.mainScroll addSubview:self.additionalAddresInfoTextField];

    self.additionalAddressLine = [self createLineUsingOrigins:self.additionalAddresInfoTextField];
    [self.mainScroll addSubview:self.additionalAddressLine];

    self.countryTextField = [self createTextFieldWithFrame:CGRectMake(LEFT_MARGIN, self.additionalAddressLine.frame.origin.y+self.additionalAddressLine.frame.size.height+SPACE_MARGIN, SCREEN_WIDTH/3, 40) andPlaceholder:AMLocalizedString(@"countryName_text", nil)];
    [self.mainScroll addSubview:self.countryTextField];

    self.countryLine = [self createLineUsingOrigins:self.countryTextField];
    [self.mainScroll addSubview:self.countryLine];


    self.zipCodeTextField = [self createTextFieldWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.countryTextField.frame.origin.x+self.countryTextField.frame.size.width+LEFT_MARGIN, self.additionalAddressLine.frame.origin.y+self.additionalAddressLine.frame.size.height+SPACE_MARGIN, SCREEN_WIDTH-SCREEN_WIDTH/3-LEFT_MARGIN*3, 40) andPlaceholder:AMLocalizedString(@"zipCode_text", nil)];
    [self.mainScroll addSubview:self.zipCodeTextField];
    self.zipCodeLine = [self createLineUsingOrigins:self.zipCodeTextField];
    [self.mainScroll addSubview:self.zipCodeLine];

    self.addOfficeLocation = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(LEFT_MARGIN, self.zipCodeLine.frame.origin.y+self.zipCodeLine.frame.size.height+SPACE_MARGIN, SCREEN_WIDTH/2, 40)];

    [self.addOfficeLocation setTitle:AMLocalizedString(@"addOfficeLocation_text", nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.addOfficeLocation setTitleColor:[UIColor greenColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.addOfficeLocation.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
    [self.mainScroll addSubview:self.addOfficeLocation];
```

Comment: What is your problem? You want to add all the 5 textfields when button pressed?

Comment: Yes, I want to add same 5 text fields, and to enter different data than in first five, and save them in array. Something like differrent locations for same company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be so many solution for your problem:

1. If you are dealing with limited set of addressed, (like 2 or 3) then all all those field on your view (`scrollView` to be specific) and show those with the button click (don't forget to increase the content size of `scrollView`). This one is **not neat** though.
2. Create a `tableView` with section for set of address fields. And every time you click the button reload the table with new section.

Let me know if you need some more information.

Comment: Hey, I thought that 2nd solution could solve the problem, but how to add those multiple cells in array(data from textfield)?

Comment: Yes that is a tricky part but not complicated. I will suggest to create an Array of dictionary in which you save data for the sections. And update respective dictionary with each update on textfield.